# Cumulative summary in ggplot2 - specify the group to connect points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can produce a simple line chart with ggplot2 with the following data.

```
structure(list(years = 2003:2014, year.count = c(4, 3, 7, 0, 
3, 6, 6, 4, 4, 8, 1, 1)), .Names = c("years", "year.count"), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(df, aes(as.factor(years), y= year.count, group=1)) + 
geom_line(colour="red") +
geom_point(colour="red") + 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

However, when I attempt to do a cumulative summary, the points are plotted without a problem but the points are not connected by the lines.

```
ggplot(df, aes(as.factor(years), y = cumsum(year.count))) + 
geom_line(group=1) +
geom_point() + 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust=1))
```

I'm guessing that the error has to do with the `group=1` argument, which I have tried specifying in `aes` and `geom_line` but neither work.  It should be a simple fix -- an explanation of the actual code or a reference to this information would be greatly appreciated.

Here are a few posts that I examined but haven't found the solution: http://goo.gl/cH0a06 http://goo.gl/5AzAcu

Comment: Using `group=1` here is a hack. If your x values were indeed categorical you shouldn't connect points with lines (or calculate the cumulative sum).

Comment: @Roland - that is the logic I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:  I removed the `as.factor` because it did not make much sense to me, although I understood that you put it in order to have a nicely labeled x-axis. That's why I modified the x-axis with `scale_x_continuous` to make it `pretty`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(years, y = cumsum(year.count))) + 
  geom_line(colour="red") +
  geom_point(colour="red") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=pretty(df$years))
```

On another note, I think it is a little bit dangerous to have operations *inside* `aes`, maybe it would be safer to compute the `cumsum` apart. That's how I would do it.

Comment: I don't understand your last point. Why do you believe calculating something in the `aes` to be dangerous?

Comment: I'm afraid it could do something bad if indeed the x values where categorical. But I'm unable to generate an example to illustrate my fear... that's even more frightening!

Comment: There is nothing to fear there. It's all happening inside a data.frame, i.e., `cumsum` doesn't care about the x values.